# ¿Cómo actualizar la rama master desde 2 ramas distintas sin perder información en git?

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-commit

Estamos trabajando dos personas en dos ramas separadas de la rama master.

¿Cómo puedo actualizar la rama master sin perder la actualizacion previa que haya hecho mi compañero desde su rama?

Answer (score 2):

Si no estáis trabajando sobre los mismos ficheros, podéis realizar un merge de cada rama y todo estará bien.

Si por el contrario estáis trabajando sobre los mismos ficheros, es necesario que hagáis un merge de una rama sobre la otra de las que estáis trabajando, resolváis los conflictos y, por último, hagáis un merge sobre master.

Answer (score 2):

Además de la forma que dice el compañero, puedes hacer una operación que se llama rebase.

Una vez tu compañero haya actualizado el Master con sus cambios, tu actualizas tu rama local de Master. Una vez hecho esto, y desde tu rama donde estas haciendo tus cambios haces lo que se llama rebase. Anteponer los commits de master a los tuyos

```
git rebase master
```

Opcionalmente puedes hacerlo iterativo con la opción de -i. Si hay conflictos sobre el mismo fichero, tendrás que resovlerlos en este punto. Y una vez resueltos que no se te olvide hacer

```
git rebase --continue
```

Una vez hecho esto, tus commits serán posteriores a los que ha hecho tu compañero y por lo tanto al añadir incluitr tus cambios en master no habrá ningún problema.

Eso si, si has subido tu rama previamente a un servidor de git, tendrás que hacer un push forzado ya que habrás reescrito la historia de la rama.

En este libro oficial de git te explica ambas formas de organizar el código
https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Ramificaciones-en-Git-Reorganizando-el-trabajo-realizado